# Two forms to snap each other

Tags: delphi, user-interface

I have a question regarding to two forms snapping each other.

For example if I move one form close to another and it's in certain distance then it's edge snaps to another forms edge. After snapping, I can move two forms by moving only one form. How can I achieve this?

I have seen this effect in Skype, DVD Decrypter and in ImgBurn.

Comment: @WarrenP Not quite the same though. OP seems to be talking about side-by-side forms, not one docked into another. I haven't seen docking implementations that do the side-by-side thing.

Comment: True. Docking usually means co-parenting on a tab-host or conjoin-host form (which JVCL JvDocking does), a floating/attached thing (TJvFormMagnet) is a closely related concept to conjoin-host docking (such forms are side by side, or above each other) and share a single frame, and have a vertical or horizontal sizer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the [`TJvFormMagnet`](http://jvcl.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jvcl/trunk/jvcl/run/JvFormMagnet.pas?revision=13167&view=markup) component of the [JVCL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvcl/files/) (JEDI Visual Component Library).

Answer (score 0):

I was using dynamically created forms and JvFormMagnet didn't seem to work for me. You can try the TMagnet Pas file component for snapping of forms to one another. A great alternative to docking. [Get it Here](https://github.com/mbirabhadra/TMagnetic-Delphi) with demo and compiled example. Its really very simple.