# Delphi 7, How can a child react to the parent form Moving?

Tags: delphi, events, delphi-7

I'm writing a `TFrame` descendant that can host any sort of controls at runtime.
Among its features, under specific conditions, it should show a sort of visual dimmed "mask".
I achieved this effect overlaying a separate `TCustomForm` descendant class with `AlphaBlend`,
and for this to work the form must have no parent.
Thus, I need some extra code to keep this window anchored to the Client area of the frame, whether it's been resized or moved.

Not a big deal for resizing: I can override `TMyFrame`'s `Resize` method.

But what about MOVING?
Let's say the frame is client-aligned to the main form: its `Left` and `Top` values don't change if I move the main window, so no `WM_MOVE` message is sent to the frame.
And I need somethig to be incapsulated INSIDE the `TMyFrame` unit, in order to keep it reusable.

Is there any other message I can handle in such a situation?

Thank you

Comment: insert an invisible control into the target form., that only function would be to send notification to your detached shadow. That is how MDI windows work in Windows ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your suggestion. The Target form is the frame's parent? Thank you

Comment: what about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106903 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook the parent form's `WindowProc` property, or subclass the parent form's window using `SetWindowSubclass()`, to intercept `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANING` and `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` messages.

Comment: That's very interesting. Didn't know about subclassing APIs, I'll investigate them. But do you think I can use this solution without affecting the parent form's code? My frame could be a child of a child of.... of the parent form being moved, so I can't rely on a specific parent window. Or, worse, I'll have to take into account the movement of any parent window in the hierarchy. Thank you.

Comment: The VCL has a `GetParentForm()` function to find the parent Form regardless of the child's nesting level. And using `SetWindowSubclass()` would be less invasive than using `WindowProc`, but either would work.